# icon-globe not found after update gem twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem. Last night I updated my gems, and tried using the `icon-globe` but all i got was an empty space.

here are my Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'bson'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'devise'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

I tried `rake tmp:clear`but this didn't worked too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

on your production environment?

Comment: it created a lot of files in my assets folder (like `application-700cf2ac13cc3bbc62c6d179910459ba.js`), but didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this the other day as well.  I have my Rails servers setup so that I can run multiple Rails apps on the same server under their own suburi.  Apparently the asset-path helper in the bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less is not including the relative path for the sprites and instead points the background-image url to /assets instead of /suburi/assets.

Following what I found here:  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3365  I was able to gather that I needed to do the folllowing when precompiling assets:

```
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT="/suburi" rake assets:precompile
```

This sets the relative root within the environment when you precompile and everything then works as it should.

The thing that really threw me for a loop was that in development everything worked just fine.  As soon as I pushed it to the production server the icons stopped showing up.  I kept thinking there was an issue with my server or my code.  All along it was just the asset-path helper not including the suburi when I precompiled my assets.

Just set your full suburi path in the RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT environment variable before running the precompile and it will work.

**Update:**  You can set this variable in the **config/application.rb** file by adding

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/suburi'
```

This would be the best option as it would not require extra typing when deploying.

You can read about it here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-controller